# Using a CSS stylesheet in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Writing a simple PHP website and having trouble linking the stylesheet to the page. In the past I've had issues with this but usually it ends up working.

Anything wrong with my code? Or am I just doing it wrong?

```
<head>
    <title>San Joaquin Valley Town Hall</title>
    <link href="styles/main.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css">
</head>`
```

(I am using a XAMPP server to run my files)

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen here for correct syntax: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: Rather that add your code as a comment, please edit the question.  It makes it easier to read.

Comment: Are both of your stylesheets not loading, or just one? Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link tag looks fine, however the href is relative.  Is the styles directory in the same directory as your html?

If you can see your stylesheet at http://yoursite.com/styles/main.css, I would change the link to be less relative:

```
<link href="/styles/main.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This way, no matter where your HTML page resides in the file structure, the stylesheet will be found.

Answer (score 1):

Without understanding your file structure, there isn't much else that can be said here.

I'd recommend using a relative link from the root directory of your project. Let's say your file structure is something like:

```
[website]
    [resources]
        [styles]
        [images]
        [js]
        ...
```

Then you're style include would be something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/styles/my_sheet.css" media="screen" type="text/css"/>
```

This is personal preference, as I'm not a fan of using directory traversal `..` or `.` to find files. In my experience, files end up moving around a bit (we develop our own framework, so things are always changing) so with this we're sure exactly where the file is located just by viewing the `href`.

Answer (score -1):

[HTML  media Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp)

Read the page that was recommended and after reading, try this:

```
<head>
  <title>San Joaquin Valley Town Hall</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/normalize.css">
</head>
```

if the next problem is the directory, try this:

```
<head>
  <title>San Joaquin Valley Town Hall</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/main.css" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/normalize.css">
</head>
```